# how can i tell which dylibs are loaded when debugging in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, dynamic-linking, dylib

I'm having some trouble with a particular library and I'm trying to test if an older version will fix my issue. The library is dynamically linked using dylib files stored near the .app file. These dylib files are all over the place and I'm not entirely sure my app is actually using the ones I'm trying to get it to use.

On visual studio you can easily look at a list of loaded dll files whilst debugging an applications. Is there any kind of similar functionality in Xcode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the debugger console, when the app is paused, you can use:

```
image list
```

From the command line you can use:

```
$ otool -L /path/to/executable
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Looking at the list, I'm surprised it's even running at all. It seems to be loading all the different versions of the library simultaneously.

Comment: I like the `-b` flag with `lldb`.   `image list -b`.